# Why am I getting a "module not found" when using console.log in my react application?

Tags: reactjs, console.log

I am attempting to use console.log() to be able to verify some values in my react application, but as soon as I type console.log() anywhere within any .js file in the src folder, the page doesn't load anymore and an error is thrown, saying I cannot import the file console-browserify/index.js because it falls outside of the src folder.
I have bootstrapped the project with npx create-react-app and normally I don't face any problems.
Here is the error as well as my package.json file : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wl87.png)

```
   {
  "name": "lovebook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@web3auth/web3auth": "^1.1.0",
    "console": "^0.7.2",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "grommet": "^2.25.0",
    "grommet-icons": "^4.7.0",
    "magic-sdk": "^7.0.0",
    "moralis": "^1.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-moralis": "^1.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3uikit": "^0.1.163"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you type "cd (your project path name)" when you create a new terminal, so any excess packages don't get installed into the node modules problem. Maybe you should recreate the project and check whether the error keeps showing. At last I'm not sure if it's gonna help much, but try reloading the server you're running your application on